# Is a question mostly pertaining to build configuration appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

I'm currently creating a somewhat complex Maven project (specifically, to automate [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529522/messagepack-in-android/#7624106)), and hence would like to submit it for review here - specifically, **the POM and the general structure of the project**.

However, a quick search for build automation tools (Maven and Ant) came out with no relevant results.

Therefore, I need to ask: in this case, would it actually be appropriate to post a review question here, in the Code Review SE?

**EDIT:** yes, I have read and re-read the FAQ. I would simply like to clarify how general the definition of "code" is on this site, since the question is actually mainly about the build execution configuration within the POM, i.e. the *coded* sequence of build plugin executions to be run.

Comment: This question is obsolete and superseded by this post: [Do configuration files constitute reviewable code?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6060/52915).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A similar question has been asked before: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180/is-this-really-code

I think that even though questions around configuration are not technically code, they're still okay to ask. It really doesn't make much sense to draw the line at code anyway because questions about configuration won't have particularly less value to future visitors than questions about code.

Comment: Yup, saw that one. I would say Jeff's answer is not relevant in this case, as this is certainly not about aesthetics - but you've addressed that. I'll wait a bit for any second opinions, and then accept your answer.